# Improving efficiency for Matlab : multiple loops with large data

Tags: matlab, loops, time, vectorization, large-data

I have the below process.

```
for x = 1:60
    for y = 1:160
        % load a 2D 'Image' from a 3d matrix
            for a = 0:52
                for b = 0:52
                    imageWin = Image((a*8+1):(a*8+96), (b*8+1):(b*8+96));    

                    for d = 1:5
                        [glcm(:,:,d),im] = graycomatrix(imageWin,'NumLevels',256,'G',[],'Symmetric', true,'Offset',d);
                    end

                    % Calculation which produce 'results' and takes 0.16 seconds
                end
              end
              finalResult(:,:,y) = result;
     end
     save(strcat('finalResult', num2str(x),'.mat'), 'finalResult');
end
```

My 3d matrix is 512x512x160x60. Therefore, one 'Image' will have 2809, 96x96 windows.

As you can see, this takes 7.5 minutes for one 'y', hence taking 19 hours to complete all 160 and much more for all 2809x160x60.

I have done a lot of improvement up to now and have no idea what can do more. Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: use `blockproc` to replace for loops of `a` and `b`. In `blockproc`, you would point the function handle to your function `graycomatrix` (along with the 5 loops of your function, so wrap the fop loop of d along with your function into another function and point handle to that). Use `parfor` for the loop of `x`, but you have to think about this since you can't save in `parfor` loop. In `blockproc`, make `UseParallel` true. Also, preallocate `glcm` and `finalResult`. Shwoing a detailed output of profiler would help you a lot in getting answers from other people.

Comment: Could you scale down the sizes to some minimum numbers and edit the code accordingly? Might be easier to test out that way.

Comment: Also when I ran with some random values, it was throwing this error - `OFFSET must be an N-by-2 array`.

Comment: Did you "run and time" it?

Comment: MATLAB has default images such as `cameraman.tif` and `peppers.png`. Write a code which puts one of these images into a 3-D array and performs whatever operation. This way it would be a standalone code. If you are absolutely sure that you cannot improve the function `graycomatrix`, then replace it with `pause(0.16)` or whatever time duration you find suitable.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar; I should give a try for what you have said above. Will come up with the results once I have done it